# How to open existing Lightning application

Tags: lightning-apps

How to open an existing Lightning application from developer console. I am able to open the Lightning Component but I don't see any option to open Lightning Application. I am using Developer Edition which is Summer 15.

Comment: when you go to File -> Open Lightning Resource menu item, you will see both the components and apps in the list. I am in my Dev Org Summer 15 and I can see both of them and open the lightning app as well.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna  I just see the components. To see the App do I need to enable any settings?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, thanks It worked but looks like there is another issue. I created Application and Component with same name I am getting this error message "duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>"

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still looking for the answer, it is pretty easy:

Dev. Console -> File -> Open Lightning Resources -> Choose the name of your app, expand it and click on the app

Answer (score 1):

Developer Console => File => Open Lightning Resources => Select the name of your app, expand it and click on the app and click on "open selected" button.